# Interleave two string arrays

Tags: java, concatenation, string-concatenation

In Java, I have something like this:

```
String[] firstname = { "name1", "name2", "name3" }; 
String[] lastname = { "lastname1", "lastname2", "lastname3" };
```

and the result I need would be something like this:

```
String[] newArray = {"name1 lastname1", "name2 lastname2", "name3 lastname3"};
```

combining one by one name  lastname into `String[] newArray` assuming the lengths are the same.

Comment: Are you using Java?

Comment: sorry, yes.... I've edited already. Thanks for your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java 7 and earlier way might be to just use a loop and iterate over all first and last names:

```
String[] fullname = new String[firstname.length];
for (int i=0; i < firstname.length; ++i) {
    fullname[i] = firstname[i] + " " + lastname[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8's Stream API and index both arrays with an stream of integers.

```
        String[] firstname = { "name1", "name2", "name3" };
        String[] lastname = { "lastname1", "lastname2", "lastname3" };

        String[] newArray = IntStream.range(0, firstname.length).boxed()
                .map(i -> firstname[i] + " " + lastname[i]).toArray(String[]::new);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
```

This yields

> [name1 lastname1, name2 lastname2, name3 lastname3]

This answers assumes, that the length of `lastname` is at least the length of `firstname`, but OP already stated that.